# How can we model viscoplastic softening using slider, dashpot & springs?

Tags: solid-mechanics

I am working on a brittle material which shows elastic behaviour followed by viscoplastic softening & hardening in the end (in compression with accumulating damage). I am not able to think of an arrangement of Spring-Dashboard-Slider system to emulate the behaviour.

Comment: Hi, welcome to engineering. if its possible, put a stress strain curve on your question. It might help others better understand your question. Even a rough sketch will be very useful.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the suggestion.